# How to make Microsoft.Web.Helpers.ReCaptcha work with X-Forwarded-Proto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-ec2, recaptcha, amazon-elb

We are using *ASP.NET Web Helpers Library 3.2.2* ([Nuget Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers/)) developing a web app that will be run on Amazon behind an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB).

It looks like all requests being sent between the ELB and web server are unencrypted. This causes context.Request.IsSecureConnection to be false.

As far as the browser is concerned the request is secure, it shows https:// and goes through port 443 as expected.

The following code in the Web Helpers Library causes some browser warnings/error when it's expecting a secure connection for all resources.

```
UrlBuilder urlBuilder = 
    new UrlBuilder(context.Request.IsSecureConnection 
        ? "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api" : 
          "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api");
```

Question: What if anything can I do about this?  Without replacing this ReCaptcha helper with a home-grown one is there anything i can do to force context.Request.IsSecureConnection to be true when it's a secure connection between the browser and the ELB?

We use `context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"]` to determine if it's on a secure connection in other places we have control over.

Comment: What uses that UriBuilder  you included in your question? Does it go back to the browser as a response redirect or does the library invoke a web request to that address internally?

Comment: It gets used in the generation of the ReCaptcha embed code that's placed on the web page.  it creates an iframe with the string representation of that urlBuilder as the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have it render the embed code to a string and then manipulate the string to change the URL if the proto header is included (or blanket set it to HTTPS).

Comment: Thanks. This might be the solution I'm looking for. Will try it out tomorrow.

Comment: Alot of times it's always the simplest solution that's best even if isn't "pretty" or "elegant"

Comment: Sometimes the easiest solutions are hard to see. :) thanks, it worked.